# What happens when you press an extra key on a keyboard?

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I am interested in knowing how a keyboard with extra keys work. So for example say I have the following keyboard:

[image]

You can see that it has extra keys. Now say that I pressed the **mute** key, what will happen in this case?

This is what I think happens:

- A signal will be sent to the computer.
- The keyboard device driver will receive this signal.
- The keyboard device driver will see that this signal is the mute signal, so it will not pass it to the OS, but rather it will call an OS function/system call that will mute the sound on the computer.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 5):

Very brief overview over the input layers:

Your keyboard device is connected to the PC in some way, for example via USB, or a PS/2 port. The kernel drivers for this mechanism know how to handle communication when a key is pressed on the keyboard.

For an USB keyboard, a standard called [HID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) (Human Interface Device) exist. This is not only for keyboards, but also for mice, joysticks and other input devices. So the device will have a *descriptor* telling the kernel what kind of signals it can emit, and a lot of the codes for keys including *mute* are standardized.

Nevertheless, some keyboards have keys that are not standardized (like the <kbd>Fn</kbd> on some keyboard), and it's up to the manufacturer how it signals those keys.

There's a special layer in the kernel for handling HID devices. This layer makes the raw HID comunication available at `/dev/hidrawX`, and then goes on to translate the HID events into kernel input events.

The kernel input layer takes *scan codes* (numbers corresponding to a physical key, unique to the deivce) and converts them into *key codes* (numbers corresponding to logical keys standardized over all devices). Both are made available as events on`/dev/input/eventX`. You can use `evdev` to see these events, and `showkey`, `dumpkeys` etc. to see the translation table.

The X server (or Wayland) reads all those events, and translates them into *key symbols* (like `a`, `á` etc., or special ones like `AudioMute`). X applications can receive this symbols, and act accordingly. You can use see `xev` application to see this layer, and configure it with `xmodmap` and the `xkbd` specification in your `xorg.conf`.

To react to `AudioMute`, some application is needed for it. Often, this is the Window Manager, but if your Window Manager doesn't do it, a separate application will also work.

So there's no single "keyboard driver", it's a lot more complicated, and there's not special call for "mute".

Comment: Let's say there are two HID devices connected to the computer (a keyboard and a mouse). Will all input from those two devices go through `/dev/hidrawX`? so if I read from this "file", will I see raw input? And how can I know which "signal" came from which device, for example if I read the value `1322362371`, how can I know if this value was sent by the keyboard or by the mouse?

Comment: The first gets `/dev/hidraw0`, the second `/dev/hidraw1`. The `X` stands for a number. Look into `dmesg` to see which device gets which. You'll see "semi-raw" input (not the USB packets, but the next level), usually a couple of dozen bytes, with the last bytes for the keys that are currently pressed. You'll need to parse the HID descriptor to understand the format. I recommend running `evtest` (as root) first and play around a bit, this is nearly "as raw" (you'll see the scancodes) as the HID data. Keyboard and mouse also get different `/dev/input/eventX` numbers (run `evtest` to see it).

Comment: When the keyboard driver receives the scan code for the mute key, can the keyboard driver contain code to mute the audio instead of passing this scan code to the window manager?

Comment: No, the keyboard driver will never do this. For starters, it doesn't know anything about the audio system, so it wouldn't know if ALSA or Pulseaudio or Jack is running, and how to execute a mute in the first place. It would also be bad design (coupling between different components). Your WM usually belongs to a particular Desktop (e.g. Gnome), so it makes assumptions about this.

Comment: I don't know if you know about how a keyboard driver works in Windows, but if you do, can this be done in Windows, that is, to make the keyboard driver mute the audio (assuming there is a WinAPI call to mute the audio)?

Comment: I don't know how it works in Windows. Windows is much more monolithic, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's some mid-level component in the OS iteself that reacts on the mute event. Doing it in the keyboard driver itself would also be extremenly bad design in Windows. Why are you so fixated on having a single driver handle everything?

Comment: *"Why are you so fixated on having a single driver handle everything?"* I want to know if someone can create a keyboard with extra buttons that can do anything one likes. For example: making a keyboard with an extra button that will open `gedit` :) if I can do the code handling in the keyboard driver, then I can simply write the code to open `gedit`. But based on what you are telling me that the scan codes must be passed to the window manager, then the window manager will not know that I want to open `gedit` unless it already knows the scan code for it.

Comment: It's exactly the other way round: It's *not* handled in the keyboard driver so you have the flexibility to configure your system to make things to like open `gedit` when you press the mute key. Replacing a kernel driver is hard: You have to write C code, you have to recompile the kernel. Configuring your WM is easy: Just edit the config files. Or use an additional program like `xte` (though you need to disable handling in the WM, only one application will get it). No need to compile anything, even non-programmers can do it.

Comment: *"Replacing a kernel driver is hard: You have to write C code, you have to recompile the kernel"* So there are two types of drivers in Linux: the kernel drivers, which needs kernel recompilation if you want to replace them, and the other types of drivers (for example: a TV Tuner driver) that are easy to replace?

Comment: No, there's *one* type of Linux kernel driver, and to modify any kernel driver, you need to know how to program in C, and you need to know how the kernel works. Which you don't, or wouldn't be asking these questions: You would be reading the code, and it would tell you all you have to know. But we are getting far from the original question now, so maybe we should stop here.

Comment: *"No, there's one type of Linux kernel driver"* I was asking about the types of drivers, not the type of kernel drivers. You said *"Replacing a kernel driver is hard: You have to write C code, you have to recompile the kernel"* so I asked if you want to replace a driver in Linux, you have to recompile the kernel?! or does this only applies to **kernel drivers**, and there are **another type of drivers** that you can install easily. if there isn't **another type of drivers**, does that mean if I want to install a printer driver, I have to recompile the kernel?!

Answer (score 1):

In general understanding, you're correct. When you press a key, keyboard sends a scancode, basically a sequence of numbers that identify each key. Scancodes are mapped to keycodes. Each keycode corresponds to a function that defines how program should react on a particular key press. Note that Xorg and console use different sets of keycodes. I don't know much about Wayland, but maybe it also uses its own set of keycodes. Keycodes are mapped to key symbols. Key symbols allow developers to work with keyboard on a higher level of abstraction.

You can see the scancodes and keycodes on console by executing `showkey --scancode` and `showkey --keycode` respectively. In Xorg you should use `xev` for the latter.

These levels of abstractions allow you to create flexible and complex mapping schemes that influence different parts of your Linux environment. This [ArchWiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys) contains a lot of information about mapping techniques and you should read it if you want to know more.

There are also a lot of [articles](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm) around the Internet that explain how keyboards work at low level. It doesn't really matter whether article was written in 1999 or 2010 - not so many things changed in keyboards since that time, but keep in mind that USB HID devices work different from 'classic' PS/2 keyboards.